# Php: retrieving primary key of one table and storing into another table while performing Insert query.

Tags: php, mysql

I have this two tables 'fcategory' and 'fthreads'. 
fcategory fields: category_id, category_name.
fthreads fields: thread_id, thread_title, category_name, category_id, user_id.

when i am creating a new thread in php, i want category_id to get fetched along with the category_name and insert it into fthreads table.

here is my php file: threads.php

```
<form action="threadsp.php" name="myform" method="post">


            <label for="field4"><span>Category</span>
                <?php
                $query = "select * from fcategory";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
                $resultsearch = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


                if(!$result){
                    die('could not get data:'.mysqli_error($conn));
                }
                echo '<select name="category" class="select-field">';

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['category_name'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
                    }

                echo "</select>";
                echo "</label>";

            ?>
            <label for="field1"><span>Thread Title <span class="required">*</span></span>
                <input type="text" class="input-field" name="title" value="" />
            </label>

            <label><span>&nbsp;</span>
                <input type="submit" value="Create"  />
            </label>
        </form>
```

second file: threadsp.php

```
 <?php

$catg = $_POST['category'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$userid = $_SESSION['uid'];


$sql = "select category_id from fcategory where category_name = '$catg'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$catgidresult = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

$query = "insert into fthreads (category_name,thread_title,user_id,category_id) values('".$catg."','".$title."','".$userid."','".$catgidresult."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(!$result){ 
    echo "failed".mysqli_error($conn);
}else{
    header("Location: question.php");
    die();
}


?>
```

i am able to fetch category_name but value of category_id shows 0.
any help will be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your threadsp.php file, you are getting array in $catgidresult variable, basically you need to pass category_id in $catgidresult, so your insert query in threadsp.php file should be as below:

```
$query = "insert into fthreads (category_name,thread_title,user_id,category_id) values('".$catg."','".$title."','".$userid."','".$catgidresult['category_id']."')";
```

Notice - $catgidresult['category_id']

Instead of generating SQL as you did, I would suggest to use bind_param.

Answer (score 1):

Why to store `category_name`  in `fthreads table` if you have category_id in that table ?? Just remove the category_name from your `fcategory table` . You need to normalize your tables. See [this](http://overflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql)  : So, just send `category_id` from your form as below :

```
<form action="threadsp.php" name="myform" method="post">


            <label for="field4"><span>Category</span>
                <?php
                $query = "select * from fcategory";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
                $resultsearch = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


                if(!$result){
                    die('could not get data:'.mysqli_error($conn));
                }
                echo '<select name="cat_id" class="select-field">';

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
                    }

                echo "</select>";
                echo "</label>";

            ?>
            <label for="field1"><span>Thread Title <span class="required">*</span></span>
                <input type="text" class="input-field" name="title" value="" />
            </label>

            <label><span>&nbsp;</span>
                <input type="submit" value="Create"  />
            </label>
        </form>
```

and in your threads.php file you can do this :

```
<?php

$cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$userid = $_SESSION['uid'];




$query = "insert into fthreads (thread_title,user_id,cat_id) values('".$title."','".$userid."','".$cat_id."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(!$result){ 
    echo "failed".mysqli_error($conn);
}else{
    header("Location: question.php");
    die();
}


?>
```

Also, you need to sanitize your input, other wise you are vulnerable to  Sql Injection . See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) is the best method to sanitize your inputs . 
Happy Coding :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try to change (inside threads.php):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['category_name'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
}
```

Into this :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
}
```

The remove (inside threadsp.php):

```
$sql = "select category_id from fcategory where category_name = '$catg'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$catgidresult = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
```

And change (inside threadsp.php):

```
$query = "insert into fthreads (category_name,thread_title,user_id,category_id) values('".$catg."','".$title."','".$userid."','".$catgidresult."')";
```

Into this :

```
$query = "insert into fthreads (category_name,thread_title,user_id,category_id) values('".$catg."','".$title."','".$userid."','".$catg."')";
```

Explaination :
You don't have to do second query to get the category_id, instead, put the category_id inside the option tag, under the value property. Basically the option tag will return the contents of value property, so put your category_id there

Comment: Thanks all u guys. all the answers helped me alot. i would love to come here again with another query. this is my first project in php. i tried  @kamal's solution thanks alot bro.